# How redeploy application on Google App Engine?

Tags: java, git, google-app-engine, deployment

I couldn't find it in the documentation, so help me please.

When I want to deploy WAR file to Google App Engine, I just clone it from git in the cloud shell and press

```
mvn appengine:deploy
```

And application successfully deploys and starts. So I have a question, when I'm fixing something, pushing in git, how to make application stop and redeploy with new, pulled changes?

Comment: Use some continuous integration tool like Jenkins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use some continuous integration tool like Jenkins or Hudson, or write your own service that will do the redeploy after detecting change in the code base.

Answer (score 2):

please have a look at this article

https://medium.com/evenbit/an-easy-guide-to-automatically-deploy-your-google-app-engine-project-with-gitlab-ci-48cb84757125

it describes how to use gitlab for deploying to Google App engine